# merging list doubles into the same type using map_if

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

[image]

It contains `Polygon`'s and also `MultiPolygon`'s. The `Polygon` elements are okay - they are doubles (and coordinates). I want to modify the "MultiPolygon" lists and get them into the same structure as the Polygon data.

I want to do 2 things:

1. Keep the Polygons as they are and extract the MultiPolygon list element which contains the "most" observations - so in this example `MultiPolygon_43155[[2]]` since it has `1 x 331 x 2`.
2. Merge the MultiPolygon doubles into a single Polygon double, that is, MultiPolygon_43155 will reduce down from 3 doubles to a single double.

One method I have been trying to use is that the MultiPolygons are lists, so I set these lists to data frames by using `map_if` along with `is.list`. (which is incorrect). The Polygons seem to be stored correctly using the defined function `is.not.list`.

```
is.not.list <- function(x) !is.list(x)
myd %>% 
  map_if(., is.list, ~map(., ~data.frame(.x)) %>% 
           bind_rows() %>% 
           arrange(X1,X2)) %>% 
  map_if(., is.not.list, ~`dim<-`(.x, tail(dim(.x), 2)) %>% # some objects have dimensions 1 x 71 x 28 - here were are just taking the tail of the dimensions - i.e. 71 x 28 and dropping the 1
           data.frame())
```

Expected output:

To have a list of all the same type (similar ot the Polygon names lists - doubles) - whether that be through merging the MultiPolygon list elements or by taking the MultiPolygon list element with the most observations.

Data:

```
myData <- list(Polygon_08286_AM = structure(c(1.68057771641075, 1.68066036773833, 
1.6806165135919, 1.68014949590425, 1.68033188446908, 1.67926599753109, 
1.67763894488799, 1.67689884667463, 1.67717730435379, 1.67591971038502, 
1.67608560791205, 1.67507539206377, 1.67972491181792, 1.68042950088666, 
1.67986502045481, 1.6800133324751, 1.68065232331268, 1.68096174425587, 
1.6802189607357, 1.66853352743185, 1.66591474466957, 1.64216041162591, 
1.6377738754204, 1.63661931700707, 1.63618766235801, 1.6353744892107, 
1.63288311440258, 1.62873204631319, 1.62042374685843, 1.61671764882099, 
1.61542203887328, 1.61748304411297, 1.61651041331774, 1.6251497086487, 
1.63975080689929, 1.64565566457873, 1.64687316848045, 1.64755514917655, 
1.64755333288212, 1.65104489494547, 1.65291113031237, 1.65181173723383, 
1.65251826218441, 1.65199140821653, 1.65230965965863, 1.65188389357304, 
1.65012400503661, 1.64625291532791, 1.64339411122966, 1.64128445068944, 
1.64077609567326, 1.6409343913637, 1.63965500627112, 1.63867667411412, 
1.63778371973947, 1.63640098107369, 1.63709397923032, 1.64176154254839, 
1.64497428675228, 1.6474290466759, 1.65054349465582, 1.65106424654449, 
1.65325897334779, 1.65506535598051, 1.65641014509384, 1.66099591493082, 
1.66066435552223, 1.66076048212061, 1.66182966740435, 1.66185008587292, 
1.66100759583174, 1.65937437222662, 1.65953595536918, 1.66175410558575, 
1.66289871048842, 1.66453189102257, 1.66663001107291, 1.66822396219368, 
1.66839854423257, 1.66787819397829, 1.66816176270049, 1.66875056576973, 
1.67074935889055, 1.67215688657136, 1.67151859165592, 1.67208694261271, 
1.67125912103271, 1.67130589894875, 1.67339736181596, 1.67353997228763, 
1.68726522415181, 1.68928260757107, 1.69002043940154, 1.69541278802561, 
1.69786978670602, 1.69878048490516, 1.70215393947531, 1.70410431562803, 
1.70801751667193, 1.7095818505711, 1.71150718694406, 1.71467663162313, 
1.71752906347833, 1.71973019850429, 1.72219448115243, 1.72163189706819, 
1.72222222880423, 1.72089220035502, 1.71968371944142, 1.71950988209199, 
1.71811505769476, 1.7166633899642, 1.71610527867916, 1.71486901263511, 
1.71386860549997, 1.71282978814457, 1.71240248341676, 1.70964281151781, 
1.70921692492593, 1.70802444279497, 1.70591892290843, 1.70490603606739, 
1.70276525646849, 1.70225709965907, 1.70225682233668, 1.70221797764603, 
1.69029222805876, 1.68950267241993, 1.68601322294219, 1.68297171518769, 
1.6767082523699, 1.67765338921014, 1.67649595286375, 1.67572441001541, 
1.67890083311975, 1.68057771641075, 41.5248863728546, 41.5246554980258, 
41.5239687692046, 41.5235856028541, 41.5233148316374, 41.522623941204, 
41.5223888579683, 41.521156475037, 41.5199944969662, 41.5187905349895, 
41.5179379514958, 41.5169624311084, 41.5138721414088, 41.5134037965875, 
41.5112208996428, 41.5106206104553, 41.5101803529775, 41.5084930514782, 
41.5071637567009, 41.5087293251724, 41.506792001063, 41.5065940327973, 
41.507896911091, 41.5076644611777, 41.5078259535847, 41.5071745027611, 
41.5080134238145, 41.5084240509274, 41.5110098537223, 41.5131308894789, 
41.5132730673522, 41.5169807545721, 41.519639994599, 41.5186528278133, 
41.5199464396834, 41.5317983528189, 41.5310647492368, 41.531217213013, 
41.5323607576481, 41.5352625749938, 41.537888015624, 41.5389320160724, 
41.5394255821188, 41.5405994337674, 41.5420271722012, 41.5431068642505, 
41.5437994891784, 41.5436322015989, 41.544378207774, 41.5443735056875, 
41.5454745489347, 41.5465125930967, 41.5465553182356, 41.548791815586, 
41.549377141805, 41.5521612187994, 41.5527994953323, 41.5530339127873, 
41.554542564268, 41.5538398803848, 41.5540222406834, 41.554052724967, 
41.5570700129636, 41.5571858034471, 41.5567170344448, 41.5634732445214, 
41.5646155173884, 41.5658592172001, 41.5675535017969, 41.5686691014517, 
41.5699548688989, 41.5710836422292, 41.5719954985101, 41.5723285259678, 
41.5739026588392, 41.5752678379225, 41.5759297979051, 41.5759189656851, 
41.5763440472709, 41.5776077219917, 41.5783795130294, 41.5788957761745, 
41.5795076736825, 41.5805668136687, 41.5816912719732, 41.582586509057, 
41.5835847240244, 41.584058912099, 41.584955124413, 41.5854354906351, 
41.5760877688266, 41.5744746998846, 41.5717524557792, 41.5731974685215, 
41.5723585856954, 41.5711958240057, 41.5712556630617, 41.570707475542, 
41.5686291327766, 41.568213793918, 41.5668291795351, 41.5655735083881, 
41.5657263206639, 41.5645103276175, 41.5623020555474, 41.5611637485402, 
41.5590686260111, 41.5579258578614, 41.5561478623472, 41.5547504412196, 
41.5528810325297, 41.5524758846474, 41.5524414452944, 41.5525823031636, 
41.5513539073632, 41.5512435206605, 41.5504777801221, 41.5482951774439, 
41.5463948720484, 41.5449942072723, 41.5438921241411, 41.5428172091, 
41.5423827593783, 41.5416562685336, 41.5416551724416, 41.5412881755293, 
41.5357973699052, 41.5376416367241, 41.5376125899439, 41.5348190533841, 
41.5310510127885, 41.5296533453223, 41.5301261352032, 41.5290438174239, 
41.5272117612074, 41.5248863728546), .Dim = c(1L, 136L, 2L)), 
    Polygon_0801505 = structure(c(2.25205336625373, 2.25067083966964, 
    2.25067838796248, 2.24850880249493, 2.24846282448231, 2.24804512058079, 
    2.24809873068868, 2.24811231435227, 2.25103857091998, 2.25295556253549, 
    2.25111661196873, 2.25046628185658, 2.25138859172188, 2.25184264014446, 
    2.25332859735521, 2.25324864206591, 2.2535242646619, 2.2574551141631, 
    2.25912352789591, 2.26034678384173, 2.26125486312464, 2.26175010769566, 
    2.26250717395873, 2.26435619125364, 2.26503044035717, 2.2681617261379, 
    2.2700802112291, 2.26767851551495, 2.26238348375544, 2.25848788553602, 
    2.254771095317, 2.25290383016258, 2.25205336625373, 41.4518777546254, 
    41.452971494451, 41.4529769377898, 41.454646533795, 41.4556159265439, 
    41.4556477397219, 41.4566099924901, 41.4566686278332, 41.4581591637314, 
    41.4586365016397, 41.459381063586, 41.4603780615581, 41.4610143020807, 
    41.4626812744223, 41.4636181481384, 41.4652313957337, 41.4654695651448, 
    41.4673975903439, 41.467554938729, 41.4689238116844, 41.4686260501564, 
    41.4691422303618, 41.4691258866333, 41.4671309701424, 41.4655526722845, 
    41.4632705270325, 41.4605317353865, 41.4593992340004, 41.4554403522709, 
    41.4525272583806, 41.4497218387842, 41.4512089988412, 41.4518777546254
    ), .Dim = c(1L, 33L, 2L)), MultiPolygon_43155 = list(structure(c(0.277097542639103, 
    0.274915177241419, 0.273789740516348, 0.271352629891711, 
    0.265971971702982, 0.263097408787634, 0.252808202569955, 
    0.248734436062416, 0.242048136111443, 0.238396898068103, 
    0.236983720620875, 0.2362145275718, 0.234165052164865, 0.233156511919391, 
    0.23391703408701, 0.244746862162007, 0.250180603676457, 0.258109192131884, 
    0.258102661150728, 0.258457148782054, 0.261104620673662, 
    0.262180734111059, 0.271195744968155, 0.271513421568636, 
    0.271880454137863, 0.270759815734341, 0.273268110357924, 
    0.276332325607379, 0.284151898676721, 0.289335348501219, 
    0.295138044661444, 0.298993142512816, 0.300403575035991, 
    0.309626471543683, 0.312724230268612, 0.317912745059885, 
    0.320128467877052, 0.317311271883114, 0.315305079137015, 
    0.312723247113849, 0.310933472657221, 0.309682668501884, 
    0.306352921827099, 0.305866325256611, 0.300304717453045, 
    0.296344665254943, 0.28824894533935, 0.284476018030332, 0.282763230651729, 
    0.285516181026275, 0.29690769883167, 0.304008570921147, 0.277097542639103, 
    40.7730644983177, 40.7763772266113, 40.776867957061, 40.7803144809912, 
    40.7802785251596, 40.7818178339817, 40.7814868013553, 40.7824939094792, 
    40.780971096132, 40.7806769431288, 40.7801312724435, 40.7803977318862, 
    40.7801485095496, 40.7793943851023, 40.7869917776333, 40.7920909536491, 
    40.7985207326615, 40.800224645411, 40.7996156801158, 40.7990975028225, 
    40.7989409630746, 40.7972077539297, 40.7992937760356, 40.7997361905309, 
    40.8040672904725, 40.8058637547142, 40.8076922848517, 40.8080650563708, 
    40.8103996013434, 40.8102252579095, 40.8127427265713, 40.8130376731604, 
    40.8135111819558, 40.8175694975927, 40.8169215166767, 40.8137647539091, 
    40.8127992541065, 40.8116842223361, 40.8090204619258, 40.8073835771731, 
    40.80833563946, 40.8084531917707, 40.806575893155, 40.8051320102635, 
    40.8045878544416, 40.8036035944692, 40.8004744969765, 40.8006271382297, 
    40.7997866215185, 40.7924216265374, 40.7879450017244, 40.7801202064611, 
    40.7730644983177), .Dim = c(1L, 53L, 2L)), structure(c(0.57327859522595, 
    0.56872327504846, 0.567517761951473, 0.565810724417504, 0.561815515255875, 
    0.561418576088311, 0.553225279868631, 0.551616003396505, 
    0.552104120864075, 0.550331767976841, 0.548307889593562, 
    0.546811420457176, 0.546480955164207, 0.543548389034336, 
    0.54209773562375, 0.540914200114959, 0.539506845537871, 0.537188794950256, 
    0.533905660076576, 0.532837234624357, 0.531820105122745, 
    0.531068288018571, 0.52832402387759, 0.525220525941882, 0.523838277825878, 
    0.521774710326472, 0.520176217523836, 0.518423013366108, 
    0.518204718985562, 0.51608234319464, 0.515478780879024, 0.513162718972518, 
    0.50676196559998, 0.50433881743096, 0.502503667358582, 0.498810146235434, 
    0.493476546511975, 0.489141843394098, 0.483281756972127, 
    0.479506005156894, 0.478712859146118, 0.475052138531779, 
    0.471072630065295, 0.468570182092159, 0.467304692465025, 
    0.465782158515019, 0.46718170472645, 0.469538740625751, 0.473490668127774, 
    0.476775476557683, 0.475347523949827, 0.475597034859493, 
    0.477052869421938, 0.476857782527853, 0.480173252919573, 
    0.487193557823064, 0.486762856238695, 0.487192938717526, 
    0.489473761389818, 0.493139135260633, 0.495554525166911, 
    0.495253138663973, 0.496095651533835, 0.49673461697951, 0.49659932972606, 
    0.497424213899128, 0.502025042795247, 0.506999655969683, 
    0.510394292683761, 0.504147345285766, 0.506514383801548, 
    0.508242202406914, 0.509111107694914, 0.5107333511718, 0.507015253639913, 
    0.504709705435397, 0.501258566664909, 0.499198017524795, 
    0.496701115101811, 0.493408083744914, 0.489973528970014, 
    0.487590754220306, 0.484111879793225, 0.48290249321491, 0.480491460370513, 
    0.479509459298096, 0.478780105148759, 0.476854673564347, 
    0.474380890022047, 0.472611751970499, 0.471270916948792, 
    0.467018512040331, 0.462862181302649, 0.457964086257992, 
    0.457919971224655, 0.456468063735203, 0.4545029631487, 0.452518213561074, 
    0.451221778511191, 0.448514500299448, 0.44605527241007, 0.444640395481207, 
    0.444268574724739, 0.440832522423211, 0.439757605096927, 
    0.438216814719557, 0.437741280902154, 0.433241979990698, 
    0.433245942584983, 0.430355057366257, 0.429295927776967, 
    0.427634022051009, 0.426319142228753, 0.423176153287604, 
    0.419419912292717, 0.418067322577295, 0.418805608055254, 
    0.417556902151276, 0.420451618891068, 0.421144851298998, 
    0.425305432957127, 0.429187902162711, 0.429744524867528, 
    0.430855590515031, 0.437357282502832, 0.440626420017421, 
    0.443095830921185, 0.451330235691298, 0.453857566656515, 
    0.454381784321124, 0.460416469955532, 0.462380565719112, 
    0.462776667014437, 0.465172220035511, 0.469505196594601, 
    0.47122698968281, 0.472360422539648, 0.474495823279643, 0.47876682925669, 
    0.479997827480672, 0.481944292099569, 0.48245996849671, 0.48371498114066, 
    0.484592723973004, 0.488020394381738, 0.490971651051886, 
    0.492337438839697, 0.494212186620444, 0.496485745048223, 
    0.497124747198731, 0.499995971233254, 0.501818793347917, 
    0.502273584220484, 0.502464484388793, 0.504013270123956, 
    0.507408993542923, 0.512259654009644, 0.512762818490482, 
    0.513081936463859, 0.514429196108035, 0.511519878078365, 
    0.510158887360571, 0.509724768911661, 0.508906838251242, 
    0.506903200146392, 0.515858255874723, 0.51712198760942, 0.522365079916814, 
    0.525332272224588, 0.541206380615086, 0.542448982803778, 
    0.543614080319982, 0.544232392622309, 0.548588756214857, 
    0.549825894538489, 0.549904264216501, 0.550356968944064, 
    0.552434202853126, 0.553031178839788, 0.554885974582312, 
    0.55660010441414, 0.560309354835866, 0.560700957513353, 0.561863429543226, 
    0.563792349791532, 0.566450002023003, 0.567584945660334, 
    0.568326534851887, 0.568010047925792, 0.568567877524308, 
    0.569151049903801, 0.569511979182671, 0.570926016231201, 
    0.573230160080372, 0.575460458417047, 0.575975355258335, 
    0.577962093046738, 0.579357743876354, 0.583053100138836, 
    0.583334295585463, 0.584429773389512, 0.587010388043084, 
    0.587814340725047, 0.587595152786084, 0.588167097628373, 
    0.590491762729799, 0.59090877829898, 0.590834706326466, 0.592071663364256, 
    0.592066340933169, 0.592883215952566, 0.593886230905441, 
    0.595576619297293, 0.596390845785824, 0.597852110620774, 
    0.598597334019951, 0.599595889540753, 0.600422384266138, 
    0.601572012305339, 0.602314663970482, 0.604059291232403, 
    0.60550313073126, 0.606988692743629, 0.617784201058204, 0.617819497759426, 
    0.622932486875266, 0.624910259026455, 0.62847493043328, 0.628876310031316, 
    0.632421391384215, 0.634350127880292, 0.636300957542589, 
    0.638857485420027, 0.640058873039653, 0.641655929156056, 
    0.642411856243078, 0.643328748171182, 0.646957880469922, 
    0.650458675211879, 0.648618199109863, 0.650293123408855, 
    0.651452613526564, 0.652091243564105, 0.651347166433166, 
    0.652003194299447, 0.653268607889033, 0.653490753146637, 
    0.655270220874723, 0.657858396666735, 0.658854733788081, 
    0.657806407547558, 0.659331207784436, 0.660814703253432, 
    0.66222030033757, 0.662012615703126, 0.663423814592484, 0.664215675731761, 
    0.664579814447848, 0.662015921759826, 0.66150766479582, 0.656046701161162, 
    0.653921836055582, 0.651879654226859, 0.653096950620937, 
    0.652833433268595, 0.653839813999234, 0.652477203489222, 
    0.653005421479827, 0.64920168999167, 0.642854226891163, 0.640999163432892, 
    0.641288764916209, 0.638624511616956, 0.637898327025592, 
    0.636394508613801, 0.634840354612603, 0.637446047261979, 
    0.636638102735812, 0.636796342196061, 0.637673542045093, 
    0.63815869549613, 0.639437294357694, 0.640211186782597, 0.641962498102384, 
    0.640591858272208, 0.642205029942742, 0.642807289743055, 
    0.638730490984946, 0.632924913986637, 0.629629257119766, 
    0.628544004797746, 0.621802813761047, 0.618261542019719, 
    0.614973598458325, 0.611537138362603, 0.607890033436697, 
    0.608648889838777, 0.609292100861032, 0.610386737391335, 
    0.611174338837667, 0.610700263258321, 0.60978335403383, 0.603366406819645, 
    0.60544787177219, 0.607164133166308, 0.607648779879521, 0.608907439439876, 
    0.608562812951362, 0.609232746155989, 0.609065945680941, 
    0.606218874226152, 0.606237906089368, 0.604921803077338, 
    0.599457398102049, 0.597967922470834, 0.59387415307139, 0.593022145106843, 
    0.590752609587834, 0.589248248520524, 0.586784800858157, 
    0.587028079839807, 0.586002614511079, 0.586363657994432, 
    0.585981536874792, 0.584349323451612, 0.587260221139289, 
    0.580881664327734, 0.579582493564393, 0.577126521376842, 
    0.575559616818865, 0.57327859522595, 40.7328812365413, 40.7469637817805, 
    40.7487769715368, 40.7500709516748, 40.751762100483, 40.750964785123, 
    40.7469410095788, 40.7461527145572, 40.7442013969855, 40.7444890407179, 
    40.7438399282017, 40.7442011874766, 40.7435539322694, 40.7458141214238, 
    40.7459672736616, 40.747092815802, 40.7478030710685, 40.7480712324526, 
    40.7475697307816, 40.7457393857583, 40.745975998741, 40.7454221265447, 
    40.7459226969959, 40.7456827781445, 40.7459783569885, 40.7434466105528, 
    40.7429916868141, 40.7432169106511, 40.7446898812002, 40.7437386606826, 
    40.7414858802742, 40.7413510633862, 40.7383038909379, 40.7391207416869, 
    40.7397393026762, 40.7384020956132, 40.7394279465155, 40.7387206316473, 
    40.7387374936565, 40.7376244992212, 40.7378651644967, 40.7371284846045, 
    40.7380139240233, 40.7379372823063, 40.7427570574137, 40.7437569320422, 
    40.7460845630382, 40.7463119315625, 40.7530712615697, 40.7567828998491, 
    40.7589255382762, 40.7671135283052, 40.77300234148, 40.7817440349377, 
    40.7857782223951, 40.7877020149382, 40.7878388825397, 40.7885913909533, 
    40.7886939674096, 40.7896720483835, 40.7894102092378, 40.7922562070479, 
    40.7922351499927, 40.793416729363, 40.7939450638448, 40.7943680128637, 
    40.8014817305715, 40.8067247461307, 40.8106096563627, 40.8094855826016, 
    40.8133844382446, 40.8162300758791, 40.8176610485379, 40.8217497682376, 
    40.8230242635823, 40.8247461766173, 40.8273234306304, 40.8264686144931, 
    40.8265613125645, 40.8259407659241, 40.8278094885074, 40.8269191508933, 
    40.8272748782747, 40.8261322652379, 40.8265034464727, 40.8272254634289, 
    40.8271123639741, 40.8281611568081, 40.8277770610184, 40.8284157962292, 
    40.8283627671981, 40.8305205253895, 40.8299334940938, 40.8321801573527, 
    40.833397270574, 40.8344230493059, 40.8342568438563, 40.83554905954, 
    40.8354697133251, 40.8365329727216, 40.838039102496, 40.8377471157, 
    40.8376703812318, 40.840013272564, 40.8398652601965, 40.8405613761943, 
    40.8403053963463, 40.8420522188741, 40.8432763375483, 40.8433258717619, 
    40.8437176731182, 40.8434519015888, 40.8441664565193, 40.8441614013364, 
    40.8456153937325, 40.8453656357994, 40.8465679697999, 40.8548004736942, 
    40.8552829663875, 40.8537674860129, 40.8523380100998, 40.8521864824538, 
    40.8526371018641, 40.8523259567334, 40.8519148809749, 40.8504494745256, 
    40.8514113818162, 40.8505615881673, 40.8514944876368, 40.8522161517664, 
    40.8489921218471, 40.8491307009937, 40.8499028771671, 40.8483088142641, 
    40.8488094255842, 40.8502429384276, 40.8528655383777, 40.8526480312008, 
    40.8528973771768, 40.8533014906324, 40.8533226173433, 40.854109107506, 
    40.8536208429038, 40.8542973336425, 40.8545262297737, 40.8540315521954, 
    40.8545130401226, 40.8540683619498, 40.8551335567943, 40.856006300111, 
    40.8562427699471, 40.8559453246533, 40.8560299903321, 40.8567182014357, 
    40.8566159310628, 40.8573597017873, 40.8562296734216, 40.8564336283014, 
    40.8565630010459, 40.8571091124903, 40.8601799270486, 40.8624819075997, 
    40.8639180823021, 40.8751463562495, 40.8846005541528, 40.8858675440514, 
    40.8868736511411, 40.888622660284, 40.8886309401832, 40.8912239762108, 
    40.891825169366, 40.8914200715363, 40.8898880665458, 40.8894657045189, 
    40.8897427666237, 40.8887676997467, 40.8883574680744, 40.8879241751236, 
    40.8888784150426, 40.8882807957891, 40.8888222536453, 40.8878430681507, 
    40.8889476802988, 40.8889387720771, 40.8895004794344, 40.8908141530423, 
    40.8907339377461, 40.8910621972461, 40.8920176367398, 40.8924596463516, 
    40.8922704692829, 40.8912596232831, 40.8915129583964, 40.8906669632391, 
    40.8910930743751, 40.8920587212236, 40.8917088204974, 40.8920617248857, 
    40.8914874727565, 40.8922982907561, 40.8921471113632, 40.8929042742521, 
    40.8937257966498, 40.8955968664853, 40.8958582357563, 40.8958308040898, 
    40.896078968274, 40.8966846615802, 40.8969523081094, 40.8975108377313, 
    40.8970350219133, 40.8971478271923, 40.8963655757481, 40.8975919695218, 
    40.897618367697, 40.897135788975, 40.8973837684781, 40.8964303029837, 
    40.8966195015463, 40.8963080831577, 40.8971811050076, 40.8964514441236, 
    40.8951801224203, 40.8898925525933, 40.8898775164468, 40.8894015598815, 
    40.8902032986432, 40.8909297091246, 40.8915559087369, 40.892786572571, 
    40.892689144675, 40.8936379039114, 40.8941509547454, 40.8950754724802, 
    40.8947632351997, 40.895561105947, 40.8945302167245, 40.8942802185073, 
    40.8936205141117, 40.8908053978786, 40.8878169522445, 40.8832322511322, 
    40.8829784031394, 40.8826136520429, 40.8820186860139, 40.8817337189223, 
    40.8812398089207, 40.8810144567608, 40.8795363364331, 40.8778189320773, 
    40.876222746403, 40.8759041297946, 40.8735604923229, 40.8725786057098, 
    40.8709641852821, 40.8692447756807, 40.8688687062635, 40.8686957668724, 
    40.8682370085523, 40.8665505308762, 40.8641039666193, 40.8612782811021, 
    40.8597333076671, 40.8581439839236, 40.8570097471747, 40.8556972947369, 
    40.8550651152239, 40.8532472020946, 40.8509362449621, 40.8489504666707, 
    40.8473430434268, 40.8450542720125, 40.8427434847166, 40.8416125483717, 
    40.8407791484945, 40.8386020694622, 40.8376839902437, 40.8365640787059, 
    40.8353432722641, 40.8349018776849, 40.833375241044, 40.8331266013705, 
    40.8321030605107, 40.8309473244449, 40.8245431805929, 40.8230512453117, 
    40.8214843658695, 40.8186948306766, 40.8174455852285, 40.8157032906437, 
    40.8147215440081, 40.813473067734, 40.8146115350752, 40.8125513397365, 
    40.8105007675252, 40.8074733990759, 40.7993897526121, 40.798348450577, 
    40.7965763692064, 40.7943825394082, 40.7892935437066, 40.7873501330774, 
    40.7800026768207, 40.7761509637089, 40.7748479827484, 40.773600034145, 
    40.7728236741063, 40.7715401728946, 40.7697383314239, 40.7687246705239, 
    40.7640520808384, 40.7621642752421, 40.7597050460049, 40.7583260388886, 
    40.7553565203421, 40.7543305290089, 40.753460457179, 40.7541713423544, 
    40.7531809529944, 40.7526042248767, 40.747690892698, 40.7446519976714, 
    40.7429955481331, 40.7425606366229, 40.7407028502212, 40.7362351362012, 
    40.7348789324239, 40.7340889393735, 40.733992251067, 40.7329346512327, 
    40.7328812365413), .Dim = c(1L, 331L, 2L)), structure(c(0.418067322577295, 
    0.417523789544143, 0.415216730182839, 0.415212243433857, 
    0.41103386583609, 0.411265133869197, 0.407891992462473, 0.404148330989403, 
    0.393977074168388, 0.377186430164456, 0.363571612703561, 
    0.362434513945456, 0.338062474604535, 0.331960921162377, 
    0.329790702013385, 0.327635271074219, 0.329887278027815, 
    0.33052953493282, 0.331364125825013, 0.332514726933399, 0.335442445313093, 
    0.336256839677575, 0.337393961904222, 0.339171100513393, 
    0.344713676519266, 0.345527849983423, 0.347544811581329, 
    0.350207949733169, 0.352311952208411, 0.355980246281343, 
    0.359061703385959, 0.361142088917527, 0.363919704610569, 
    0.363522383060355, 0.395682250854166, 0.418067322577295, 
    40.8453656357994, 40.8424013545876, 40.8388307595141, 40.8334273142747, 
    40.8287244608915, 40.8279070858467, 40.8257103606642, 40.8255339911777, 
    40.8236979723994, 40.8222381736882, 40.817925181347, 40.8202914653944, 
    40.8042854639703, 40.8012451968649, 40.8012291208874, 40.8041001525684, 
    40.8057552491809, 40.8057997329498, 40.8051913513369, 40.8059236046603, 
    40.8059188096392, 40.8067958396063, 40.8072493950217, 40.8100706665827, 
    40.8123331174672, 40.8132016367301, 40.8139434753919, 40.8143349580797, 
    40.8151557794767, 40.8190206484089, 40.8208851466783, 40.8214639105529, 
    40.823175047134, 40.827275903692, 40.8371313073429, 40.8453656357994
    ), .Dim = c(1L, 36L, 2L))))
```

EDIT:

packages:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear on the expected result but try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlist)

res <- myData %>%
  map_at(.at = grep("Multi", names(.)), ~ keep(.x, lengths(.x) == max(lengths(.x)))) %>%
  rapply(function(x) if (is.array(x)) `dim<-`(x, tail(dim(x), 2)) else x, how = "list") %>%
  list.flatten()

str(res) 

List of 3
 $ Polygon_08286_AM  : num [1:136, 1:2] 1.68 1.68 1.68 1.68 1.68 ...
 $ Polygon_0801505   : num [1:33, 1:2] 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
 $ MultiPolygon_43155: num [1:331, 1:2] 0.573 0.569 0.568 0.566 0.562 ...
```

Comment: This solution keeps the maximum length list element in "MultiPolygon"? This is almost what I want. The "MultiPolygon" is still a list. Would `unlist` work to just remove the list of lists for the MultiPolygon? Then I will have just a single list of doubles.

Comment: @user8959427 - updated to hopefully what you're after.